# Specify a static ip address for azurerm_batch_pool with azurerm_public_ip with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, static-ip-address

Can i specify variable `ip_address = "10.0.0.4"  # Specify the static IP address here`
in azurerm_public_ip? The problem is I need to extract data from external data sources hosted on client servers. They have whitelisted my vm ip address for this. Earlier I was using dedicated nodes running and got my ip_address whitelisted. but now i want to change it with autoscaling which will scale up the vms only when a task is triggered but doing so my ip_address changes everytime the vm spins the node. I have specified now `network_configuration` in azurerm_batch_pool with `public_ips =[azurerm_public_ip.static_ip.id]` Can i specify ip_address in static_ip to my previous whitelisted ip so the trasnfers can go on without asking them to whitelist my new ip address?

```
resource "azurerm_batch_pool" "example" {
name                = lookup(var.batch_prediction, "pool_name")
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
account_name        = azurerm_batch_account.example.name
vm_size             = lookup(var.batch_prediction, "vm_size")
node_agent_sku_id   = lookup(var.batch_prediction, "node_agent_sku_id")

auto_scale {
}


storage_image_reference {
}

start_task {
  command_line         = lookup(var.batch_prediction, "start_script")
  max_task_retry_count = 2
  wait_for_success     = true

  user_identity {
    auto_user {
    }
  }
  resource_file {
  }
}

certificate {
}


network_configuration {
  subnet_id                        = local.subnet_pred
  public_ips                       = [azurerm_public_ip.static_ip.id]
  public_address_provisioning_type = "UserManaged"
}

}
```

and for my azurerm_public_ip is:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "static_ip" {
  name                = var.pub_ip_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = lookup(var.pub_ip_grp, "sku")
  allocation_method   = lookup(var.pub_ip_grp, "alloc_meth")
  domain_name_label   = var.pred_pub_ip_name
}
```

Comment: can be done with [ip_address = "10.0.0.4"](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/public_ip)

Answer (score 0):

Using Terraform reference I was able to azurerm_batch_pool with azurerm_public_ip.

Yes, you can specify the static IP address in `azurerm_public_ip` resource block by setting the `ip_address` parameter to the desired IP address is one possible way to implement it.
Reference:

> Thank for the [reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/public_ip) [@nextopsvideos](https://github.com/nextopsvideos/terraformyt)

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" 
 "static_ip" 
 { 
 name =  "example-public-ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name 
  location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location sku =  "Standard"
   allocation_method =  "Static" domain_name_label =  "example-public-ip" 
   ip_address =  "10.0.0.4"
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]